# Json object sending to server parse error

Tags: android, json, post

I have an app which needs to upload some text.

I am using the Fast Android Networking library.
(https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking)

From the sample, i copied the code to test the server, but every time I get parseError.

I tried with HTTPRequester for Mozilla(Addon) and it works.

The json object looks like this:

```
 {
 "full_name":"john",    
 "email":"john@gmail.com",    
 "phone":"123214",     
 "mobile_phone":"+38163600100",    
 "address":"LA street 2",       
 "place":"LA",    
 "action":"new_session"
 }
```

Added the library on dependencies, also internet permission and access network state in androidmanifest.

On the onCreate method I implemented this(as required):

```
 AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());
 connect();
```

Connect function:

```
public void connect()
{
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("full_name", "John");
        jsonObject.put("email", "john@gmail.com");
        jsonObject.put("phone", "123456");
        jsonObject.put("mobile_phone", "54525");
        jsonObject.put("address", "LA");
        jsonObject.put("place", "LA street 2");
        jsonObject.put("action", "new_session");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AndroidNetworking.post("http://example.com")
            .addJSONObjectBody(jsonObject) // posting json
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("data", response.toString());

                    try {

                        Log.i("data", response.toString());
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String client_id = jresponse.getString("client_id");
                            String status = jresponse.getString("status");
                            String session_id = jresponse.getString("session_id");
                            Log.i("dataJson", client_id);
                            Log.i("dataJson", status);
                            Log.i("dataJson", session_id);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    if (error.getErrorCode() != 0) {
                        error.getErrorCode();
                        error.getErrorBody();
                        Log.d("dataJson", "onError errorCode : " + error.getErrorCode());
                        Log.d("dataJson", "onError errorBody : " + error.getErrorBody());
                        Log.d("dataJson", "onError errorDetail : " + error.getErrorDetail());

                    } else {

                        Log.d("dataJson", "onError errorDetail : " + error.getErrorDetail());
                        Log.d("dataJson", "onError errorCode : " + error.getErrorCode());
                        Log.d("dataJson", "onError errorBody : " + error.getErrorBody());
                        Log.d("dataJson", "obj" + jsonObject);


                    }
                }
            });


}
```

I logged out everything to see what is happening:

```
  07-26 11:45:32.090 21337-21337/? D/dataJson: onError errorDetail :parseError
  07-26 11:45:32.090 21337-21337/? D/dataJson: onError errorCode : 0
  07-26 11:45:32.090 21337-21337/? D/dataJson: onError errorBody : null
  07-26 11:45:32.090 21337-21337/? D/dataJson: obj{"full_name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com","phone":"123456","mobile_phone":"54525","address":"LA","place":"LA street 2","action":"new_session"}
```

I select this json object, past it to HTTPRequester, and its okay. What am I missing?

response:

```
     {
     "client_id": 2,
     "status": "ok",
     "session_id": "furpnvflbsh6414hkf2k8a83i7" 
     }
```

Comment: Whats your post url ?

Comment: the url is okay. if I mistype, i get a network connection error.

Comment: http://example.com is this your url ?

Comment: I am also getting the same... Did you solve it ?

Comment: Yes, the server waits JsonObject, but i tried to send an array. That was the problem in my case.

Comment: use getAsJSONObject